# STM32F103C8T6 HAL_SPI_Transmit_DMA doesn't work well

Tags: stm32, spi, dma

I am writing basic SPI loopback example with STM32F103C8T6 with CubeMX( spi1 is master and spi2 is slave). SPI2 is configured with DMA Circular mode

```
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(CS_GPIO_Port, CS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    hal_status = HAL_SPI_Transmit_DMA(&hspi2, u8_SPI2_TxBuff, sizeofBuff); //OK
    HAL_Delay(1000);
    HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi1,u8_SPI1_RxBuff,sizeofBuff,100);
    HAL_Delay(1000);
    hal_status = HAL_SPI_Receive_DMA(&hspi2, u8_SPI2_RxBuff, sizeofBuff); // HAL BUSY
    HAL_Delay(1000);
    HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1,u8_SPI1_TxBuff,sizeofBuff,100);
    HAL_Delay(1000);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(CS_GPIO_Port, CS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
  /* USER CODE END 2 */
```

There is an problem at the second DMA call :
hal_status = HAL_SPI_Receive_DMA(&hspi2, u8_SPI2_RxBuff, sizeofBuff);
hal_status return hal_busy
But when i change DMA to interrupt, it works well:

```
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(CS_GPIO_Port, CS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    hal_status = HAL_SPI_Transmit_IT(&hspi2, u8_SPI2_TxBuff, sizeofBuff);
    HAL_Delay(1000);
    HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi1,u8_SPI1_RxBuff,sizeofBuff,100);
    HAL_Delay(1000);
    hal_status = HAL_SPI_Receive_IT(&hspi2, u8_SPI2_RxBuff, sizeofBuff);
    HAL_Delay(1000);
    HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1,u8_SPI1_TxBuff,sizeofBuff,100);
    HAL_Delay(1000);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(CS_GPIO_Port, CS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
  /* USER CODE END 2 */
```

Am I missing some step with DMA?

Answer (score 1):

Circular buffer mode is a feature of the DMA as you noted. When you start your transmit with DMA, with circular buffer mode enabled, then the transmit will run forever unless you manually stop it. Therefore, from your first code sample, for SPI2, you have this:

```c
HAL_SPI_Transmit_DMA(&hspi2, u8_SPI2_TxBuff, sizeofBuff);
HAL_SPI_Receive_DMA(&hspi2, u8_SPI2_RxBuff, sizeofBuff); // HAL BUSY
```

The HAL is returning `HAL_BUSY` because your DMA transmit has not stopped. It is just looping around and around your buffer. You would need to first stop it with `HAL_SPI_DMAStop()`.

The reason your second code sample works (or at least doesn't report `HAL_BUSY`) is that the interrupt driven transmit and receive routines don't implement a circular buffer. They just send (or receive) the buffer once, and then stop.